# how long can Spring JdbcTemplate wait for an oracle stored procedure to finish

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate, sqlexception

my java code is like:

```
logger.info("start");
getJdbcTemplate().execute("call " + procedureName + "()");
```

and I got the exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: StatementCallback; SQL [call PRMI_UPDATE_USER_LOGIN_INFO()]; Io ERROR: Connection reset; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Io ERROR: Connection reset
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:257)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:407)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:428)
```

Maybe it's caused by the long time waiting. I found that it printed "**start**" in log and after about 5 minutes I got the exception.

**update** at 2013-03-13:

I got that exception not only at calling oracle stored procedure but at druid's 'JdbcUtil.close(...)':

```
com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.close:81 - close connection error
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:101)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:500)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:3509)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.connection_close(FilterChainImpl.java:167)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.stat.StatFilter.connection_close(StatFilter.java:254)
    at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.connection_close(FilterChainImpl.java:163)
    at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.ConnectionProxyImpl.close(ConnectionProxyImpl.java:115)
    at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.close(JdbcUtils.java:79)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.shrink(DruidDataSource.java:1876)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource$DestroyConnectionThread.run(DruidDataSource.java:1694)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:150)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:180)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:169)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:117)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:77)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1010)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.receive(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:97)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:487)
```

The druid's JdbcUtil.close method is quite simple:

```
 public static void close(Connection x) {
    if (x == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        x.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.debug("close connection error", e);
    }
}
```

the source code is :
https://github.com/alibaba/druid/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/druid/util/JdbcUtils.java

Answer (score 2):

It should wait as long as it is needed. Forget about various hacks which try to "detect" deadlock based on timeout delay.

- you should find also some ORA-XXXX error. `Io ERROR: Connection reset` does not look like Oracle error message, there should be some error number attached to it
- the timeout 5 minutes is very strange value. Theoretically this can be setup also on database side. As profile parameter `CPU_PER_CALL` but in such a case you should get an error: `ORA-02393: exceeded call limit on CPU usage`. And you connection should NOT be lost
- theoretically you can also have problems which dead connection detection, but 5 minutes timeout is too short for that
- another possible source can be ORA-600 error. Oracle internal error, maybe your session process crashed and therefore TCP connection was lost
- you should contact your local DBAs and ask then for cooperation. They should help you better than anonymous people on the Internet forum.

Comment: thanks for you advise, but our DBAs donot think the problem is the database

Comment: then simply call your function from sqlplus (or SQLDeveloper) and you will see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe it's caused by the long time waiting

**No it is not caused due to that**

As Java Doc says about [DataAccessResourceFailureException](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessResourceFailureException.html#DataAccessResourceFailureException%28java.lang.String%29)

> Data access exception thrown when a resource fails completely: for
>   example, if we can't connect to a database using JDBC.